# Почему не дает авторизироваться по QR коду в webauthn?

Tags: javascript, авторизация, auth

Есть сайт https://webauthn.io/ при нажатии кнопки регистации отображается окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя я ожидаю это окно, которое дает возможность выбрать автоизацию через qr или другие методы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу понять почему мне дают выбрать авторизоваться через QR, а сразу дают ввести пинкод и браузерное окошко даже не появляется, при том что на этом же сайте на другом компьютере всё работает как я хочу